# How to open bottom sheet without context(deep link)

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to open bottom sheet with the help of deep link  but it couldn't make it due to the context.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a global key for your navigation

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Pass into MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyDemoApp',
      onGenerateRoute: generateRoute,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
```

Push to routes or open bottom sheet using global context. Exp:

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/someRoute');
```

[See also](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074)

2nd option is [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it)

Answer (score 1):

Use [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) plugin like this

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Show bottomsheet'),
  onPressed: () {
    Get.bottomSheet( 
      Container(
        height: 150,
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Text'),
          ],
        )
      ),
      barrierColor: Colors.red[50],
      isDismissible: false,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        side: BorderSide(
          width: 5,
          color: Colors.black
        )
      ),
      enableDrag: false,
    );
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Get.bottomSheet(//your widget);
```