# Why my banner is not displaying in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display a banner whenever internet is disconnected in my flutter app, but it is not displaying.

Here is my code, I used this in MyApp:

```
return InternetConnectivityListener(
      connectivityListener: (BuildContext context, bool hasInternetAccess) {
        debugPrint("Checking");
        if (hasInternetAccess) {
          showToast("Internet is Active");
          return const MaterialBanner(content: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
            child: Text('You are back Online'),
          ), actions: [], backgroundColor: Colors.green,);
        } else {
          showToast("Not Connected to Internet");
          return const MaterialBanner(content: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
            child: Text('No Internet Connection'),
          ), actions: [], backgroundColor: Colors.red,);
        }
      },
      child: MultiProvider(
```

The Snackbar is working perfectly, but I want to show a banner instead.

I even tried to show bottomSheet, but it was also not displayed in my app.

Answer (score 0):

the `showBottomSheet` show function shows a bottom sheet on the current screen context, so you need to give it the current opened screen context.
you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824425/how-to-open-bottom-sheet-without-contextdeep-link) for some solutions.